# Spam filtering: where do I start

Tags: c#, asp.net, spam-prevention

I have created a new asp.net site (web forms, c#) and looking to make it secure against spam coming through textboxes and being added to the database. Does anyone have any good links on how to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I use ReCaptcha for this. 
You can download it from [nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/recaptcha) or install with

```
Install-Package recaptcha
```

command through package management console

```
 public class NoCache : ActionFilterAttribute
{

public class CaptchaValidatorAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private const string CHALLENGE_FIELD_KEY = "recaptcha_challenge_field";
    private const string RESPONSE_FIELD_KEY = "recaptcha_response_field";
    private const string CAPTCHA_MODEL_KEY = "Captcha";

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var captchaChallengeValue = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[CHALLENGE_FIELD_KEY];
        var captchaResponseValue = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[RESPONSE_FIELD_KEY];
        var captchaValidtor = new Recaptcha.RecaptchaValidator
        {
            PrivateKey = "key",
            RemoteIP = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress,
            Challenge = captchaChallengeValue,
            Response = captchaResponseValue
        };

        var recaptchaResponse = captchaValidtor.Validate();

        if (!recaptchaResponse.IsValid)
        {
            filterContext.Controller
                .ViewData.ModelState
                .AddModelError(
                    CAPTCHA_MODEL_KEY,
                    "Entered text is invalid");
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}

public static class CaptchaExtensions
{
    public static string GenerateCaptcha(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        var captchaControl = new Recaptcha.RecaptchaControl
        {
            ID = "recaptcha",
            Theme = "white",
            PublicKey = "key",
            PrivateKey = "key"
        };
        var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter());
        captchaControl.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
        return htmlWriter.InnerWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Than you can use

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("activate_user", , FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Email)
 <div class="captcha">
    @Html.Raw(@Html.GenerateCaptcha())
    <div style="text-align:center; margin-left:-25px;">
    @Html.ValidationMessage("Captcha")       
    </div>
 </div>       
 <input type="submit" class="signUpButton active activation" value="Activate" />
}
```

And in controller:

```
    [ActionName("activate_user")]
    [CaptchaValidator]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ActivateUser(string email)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, false);
            Repository.ActivateUser(email);     
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: @PhilPursglove - What was posted is exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have spam, I wouldn't worry about it.

That being said, if you do have it, you want to know what kind of spam you are getting.  Validating the input against the model should prevent most of it assuming you have restrictions on the valid input.  If just about anything validates, or you have to accept everything for some reason, you can start with a honey pot, which is a simple, non intrusive method.

To implement a honey pot, you basically add a field, hide it with CSS and and validate that field is null on the server side.  Most spam bots fill out all fields and this will identify when something automated has submitted the form.

If you find this ineffective in preventing all spam on your site, you need to see what kind of spam is getting through and find something that prevents that.  As a last resort, you can move to intrusive actions such as recaptcha.  The real issue with CAPTCHA's (as [Eric Lippert's succinctly states it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/10/sorry-about-the-captcha.aspx)) is that they assume guilt, that the user is trying to do something bad, and that has a negative effect on your users.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest that you take the [Growmap Anti-Spam plugin](http://www.growmap.com/growmap-anti-spambot-plugin/) for WordPress and convert its Javascript and PHP implementation to something you can use in your project. It's not as annoying as CAPTCHA to end users and it's been quite effective in stopping automated spam on my WordPress blogs. It shouldn't be a big deal to do the ASP.NET/C# conversion. I started on one but the project I was doing it for got canceled so I didn't complete it.

Of course, it won't help with manual spamming where somebody pays $5 for someone sitting in a third world Internet cafe to enter nonsense onto dozens of sites. This is also a problem for many other anti-spam systems, including CAPTCHA. This activity is primarily done to get links for SEO purposes so screening out links for moderation or preventing them from being entered can curtail this activity.

Comment: He is neither using WordPress nor PHP.  There are already solutions written in C#, why cause the author extra work, work that he might not actually be up to.

Comment: @Ramhound - I knew I should have put this as a comment since some know-it-all would down vote it. The 'solutions' I've seen in C# are user-UNfriendly CAPTCHA solutions. I was trying to offer a viable and more user friendly alternative but I guess that's not good enough for some people. People like you are making the whole stack exchange system an unfriendly experience.